# Start another .bat in .bat with wait option

Tags: batch-file, admin

I have little problem, because I must in my first .bat start another .bat with admin pass.
There I have problem, because when i use start /wait to start second .bat when all operations finish second cmd window doesn't closing and view directory. Or when I use [this method](http://www.techgainer.com/create-batch-file-automatically-run-administrator/) in second bat wants admin pass whereupon open thierd cmd window and in second vie directory.

First bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
start /wait test2.bat
pause
```

Second bat

```
@echo off
:: BatchGotAdmin (Run as Admin code starts)
REM --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )
:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B
:gotAdmin
if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
call notepad.exe
pause
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't link to your dropbox as it turns your question into a private consultation.

Comment: Hard to understand your aim: you are talking in slightly unclear terms _first batch_, _second batch_ in contradiction to `test2.bat` (is it _first_, _second_ or entirely other one?). Of course, `notepad` is launched with elevated privileges. Hence, instead of `call notepad.exe` use `start "" notepad.exe` and the second window will close (or rather show `Press any key to continue . . .` due to `pause` command).

Comment: First batch I start double-click and I called it test1.bat. 
Second batch is test2.bat and it must started when test1.bat call him.

Notepad.exe isn't important ( its only to test2.bat do something)

problem is with opening thierd cmd window and directory in cesond window (because this directory permanently stop my test1.bat).

Comment: How I can contact private with you Magoo?